# merge many polygon from json map api v3

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to find method to merge many polygon ( >100 ) in order to have only 1 polygon to have just the border of the merged polygon, not border for all "little" polygon

I import coordinates from JSON file and I use this code to render each polygon:

```
            var thisUcVar<?php echo $nb_fichier ?>;
            var thisAgencyVar<?php echo $nb_fichier ?>;
            var thisListAgencyVar;
            var thisUcColor;
            $.getJSON("<?php echo("test/". $fichier); ?>", function(json1) {
                var i=0;
                var coordUc = [];
                var thisUc = json1;
                thisUcVar<?php echo $nb_fichier ?> = thisUc[0].name;
                thisAgencyVar<?php echo $nb_fichier ?> = thisUc[0].agency;
                thisUcColor = thisUc[0].color;
                $.each(json1, function(key, data){
                    i = 0;              
                    $.each(data.coordinates, function(key, data){              
                        coordUc.length = 0;
                        $.each(data, function(key, data){
                            var innerCoordUc = {"lat":  data[1], "lng": data[0] };
                            coordUc[i] = innerCoordUc;
                            i++;
                        });
                        var uc = new google.maps.Polygon({
                            title: i,
                            strokeWeight: 1,
                            fillColor: thisUcColor,
                            paths: coordUc,
                            zIndex: 10
                        });             
                        uc.setMap(map);
                        map.addListener('zoom_changed',function(){
                            if(map.getZoom()>=10){
                                uc.set('zIndex', 90);
                            }else{
                                uc.set('zIndex', 10);
                            }
                        });
                        uc.addListener('click', function() {
                            $(".layer").html("<h1>" + thisUcVar<?php echo $nb_fichier ?> + "</h1><ul></ul>");
                            $.each(thisAgencyVar<?php echo $nb_fichier ?>, function(key, data){
                                listThisAgencyVar = data.name;
                                $(".layer").append("<li>" + uc.title + listThisAgencyVar + "</li>");
                            });
                            if(map.getZoom() >= 10){
                                map.setZoom(11);
                                map.setCenter(uc.getBounds().getCenter());                                  
                            } 
                        });

                        if (!google.maps.Polygon.prototype.getBounds) { 
                            google.maps.Polygon.prototype.getBounds=function(){
                                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds()
                                this.getPath().forEach(function(element,index){bounds.extend(element)})
                                return bounds;
                            }        
                        }
                    }); 
                });//fin de boucle json1        
            });
```

Result is like image below: [image: image with all polygon]

And here one of the JSON files that I'm using to generate each polygons. 
[JSON used to generate polygons group](https://jsfiddle.net/Lddz3w22/)

I search everywhere and I didn't find any way to merge many polygons in one big ...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that might work is using the [Turf library](http://turfjs.org/). In particular, it has a [union](http://turfjs.org/docs/#union) method that does exactly what you want (merge multiple polygons into one that corresponds to the union of the polygons).

However, this library uses the [Geojson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON) standard format so you will need to convert your data into this standard.

If you can use this format, it will also help you to display the data on the map using a DataLayer and the [loadGeoJson](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#load_geojson) method from Google Maps API.